# Unbounded continuous functions attain maximum on certain sets

Tags: real-analysis

Q Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a compact set, $a$ be a limit point of $A$. Let $f$ be a real-valued function that is continuous o the set $A \backslash\{a\} .$ Prove that if $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=-\infty$, then $f$ attains a maximum on $A \backslash\{a\}$.

Can we use the extreme value theorem for compact sets? But, this theorem talk about the extremes, and we see that limit goes to negative infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $\delta>0$, the function $f$ attains
its maximum $f(x_\delta)$ on the compact set $A\setminus ]a-\delta,a+\delta[$.

Claim:  There exists $\delta_0>0$ such that
$$f(x_{\delta_0})=\max_{A\setminus\{a\}}f.$$

We prove the claim by contradiction: Assume that for each $\delta>0$
there exists $y_\delta \in ]a-\delta,a+\delta[\setminus \{a\}$ such that $f(y_\delta)> f(x_\delta)$.

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=-\infty$,
then there exists $\delta_1>0$ such
that $f(x)<-|f(x_{\delta_1})|$ for each $x\in ]a-\delta_1,a+\delta_1[$.
In particular
$$f(x_{\delta_1})<f(y_{\delta_1})<-|f(x_{\delta_1})|$$
which is a contradition.